Numerically computing CDF from MGF + CF
Let $X$ be a continuous real random variable.
For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i^2=-1$, $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$ is the characteristic function of $X$.
For $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]$ is the moment generating function of $X$.
I'm interested in computing sharp tail bounds on $X$ from its characteristic function and moment generating function.
We can obtain the (complementary) CDF of $X$ from the characteristic function via the Gil-Pelaez inversion formula: $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge x] = \frac12 + \frac1\pi \int_0^\infty \frac1t \Im(\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]e^{-itx}) \mathrm{d}t = \frac12 + \frac1\pi \int_0^\infty \frac1t \mathbb{E}[\sin(t(X-x))] \mathrm{d}t. \tag{1}$$
Let $s>0$ and assume $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]<\infty$.
We have $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge x] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{(s+it)X}]e^{-(s+it)x}}{s+it} \mathrm{d}t.\tag{2}$$
The expectation $\mathbb{E}[e^{(s+itX)}]$ is the tilted characteristic function; this blends the moment generating function with the characteristic function.
The second integral can be better numerically than the first integral when $x$ is large (and, thus, $\mathbb{P}[X \ge x]$ is small), because of the $e^{-sx}$ factor.
To evaluate $\mathbb{P}[X\ge x]$ numerically, I need to approximate the infinite integral (2) with a finite sum. My question is about how best to do this.
If we can only afford one evaluation, then we have $$\mathbb{P}[X \ge x] = \mathbb{P}[e^{s(X-x)}\ge 1] \le \mathbb{E}[e^{s(X-x)}]. \tag{3}$$ This is the classic Markov's inequality tail bound. This bound is reasonably tight when $X$ is, say, a Gaussian. But if we evaluate $\mathbb{E}[e^{(s+it)X}]$ at more points, we should be able to make it tighter.
My Question: Suppose we can evaluate $\mathbb{E}[e^{(s+it)X}]$ at $n$ values of $t$. Our goal is to compute an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}[X \ge x]$? What is the right set of points to evaluate at and how tight a bound can we get?
To make the question precise, I need to specify how "best" is defined:
I want a method that gives an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}[X \ge x]$ for any well-behaved $X$. But how good the upper bound is will be measured for a specific distribution; namely, $X \gets N(0,1)$. I.e., we will try to minimize the upper bound when $$\mathbb{E}_{X \gets N(0,1)}[e^{(s+it)X}] = e^{(s+it)^2/2} - e^{(s^2-t^2)/2} (\cos(st)+i \sin(st)).\tag{4}$$
Note that I'm restricting to computing an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}[X \ge x]$ because I'm interested in the regime where $s>0$ and $x \to \infty$.
Formal Question Statement:
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $s>0$, and $x>0$, determine $t_1, \cdots, t_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w_1, \cdots, w_n \in \mathbb{C}$ which satisfy the constraint below and (approximately) minimize the objective below.

Constraint: $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R} ~~~~~ \sum_{k=1}^n w_k e^{(s+it_k)y} \ge \mathbb{I}[y \ge 0].\tag{5}$$
Objective: $$\mathsf{minimize} ~~~~~ \sum_{k=1}^n w_k \mathbb{E}_{X \gets N(0,1)}[e^{(s+it_k)(X-x)}] = \sum_{k=1}^n w_k e^{(s+it_k)^2/2-(s+it_k)x}.\tag{6}$$

Equation 3 gives the optimal answer when $n=1$. (Optimality follows from the fact that we need $\sum_{k=1}^n w_k e^{(s+it_k)y}$ to be real, so $t_1=0$ is the only choice.)
In general, I don't think we will find the exact optimal answer, but I'm hoping someone has a good idea for how to do this.
You may expect that the right thing to do is to discretize and truncate the integral (2). Unfortunately, the convergence is fairly slow. This does not yield good results in practice.
The plot below shows what you get with $s=1$ by trucating the integral (2) to $t \in [-10,10]$ and discretizing with unit step size (i.e., replace the integral with a sum over $t\in\{-10,-9,\cdots,10\}$). This corresponds to $n=21$ evaluations.
This is about as good as I could get it by playing around with the parameters. You will note that this does not produce an upper bound either.

